# Responsive Footer Design in Reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with the responsive design of a footer with reactstrap. Given below is the code snippet for the footer.

```
const Styles=styled.div`
    .navbar{
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
    }
`;
const Column = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 10px 30px auto 30px;
`;
const Line = styled.hr`
    border: solid 1px grey;
    width: 700px`;

const Footer = () =>{
    return(
            <Styles>
                <Navbar className="navbar-fixed-bottom">
                    <Container className="justify-content-center">
                        <Row> 
                           . 
                           .
                           .
                        </Row>
                        <Row><Line/></Row>
                    </Container>
                    <Container className="justify-content-center"><Row><HeadingList>© CEC CSE Department</HeadingList></Row></Container>
                </Navbar>
            </Styles>
    )
}
```

The above code works fine if there's enough content to fit the page. But if there is not, then the below problem occurs

[image]

As it's evident from the picture, there's so much white space below the footer. How can I solve this issue? I've tried overriding the CSS position to `sticky` with `bottom` 0, but it creates problem when there's more than enough content to fit the page.

Some other responsive solutions are much appreciated.

Comment: Whenever this happens, I just add a container below the content with enough height to push the footer past the viewport, otherwise, if you want it to be positioned on the bottom no matter what, you could do a `position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;`

Comment: I tried that, but it messes up whenever there's more content.

Comment: what is the end result that you're looking for? if you're just looking at putting the footer on the bottom regardless of the body content, then set it to absolute, and set the `z-index` to 9999 or something like that so all content goes below it.